# Why does div tag not working as a wrapping block?

Tags: html, css

I use  to make a card. However, the  doesn't seem to offer any boundary at all and thus the entire page has the background color of body. I have tried to tinker around, changing the place of  but it doesn't work. Why is this? Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/main.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>{{ form.csrf_token }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.tweet_text()}}</div>
    <div>{{ form.tweet_image()}}</div>
<div>{{ form.submit()}}</div>
</form>

<div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/news/2009/10/27/facebook1_sq-17f6f5e06d5742d8c53576f7c13d5cf7158202a9.jpg?s=16" alt="" />
        <h1>Rohit Falor</h1>
        <p>From the restored 540 K Streamliner to the all-new S65 AMG Coupe to the Concept Coupe SUV.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color : azure;
    }
.card{
     height: 100px;
     width: 350px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888;
     border-top: 10px solid green;
     min-height: 250px;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     }
img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects have no `background-color` attribute by default (the default is transparent).  If you are looking to give it something other than a transparent `background-color`, you need to define it.

The easiest way to do this would be to set the following attribute in your `.card` class definition:

```
background-color: white;
```

or

```
background: white; /* This allows for more attributes */
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The entire page is still azure as if the card layout isn't there at all.

Comment: Make sure you add this within the brackets {} of the .card class definition.  When I tested it, it worked fine.

Comment: I see that it works on that page, but it doesn't work when I copy the code back into my IDE and run on local server.

Comment: @JokerFan  Now, even changing the body background color doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you're either not updating the correct file(s), or your code is pointing to the wrong `.css` source.

Comment: I just found out the problem. my browser is caching and not updating the new content. Thanks for you guys' help.